# Get all userid friends give unnexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql

lets say:

```
table users(id, name, ..)
table friends(uid, fid)
```

How can i get some 33456 user id friends?

```
 SELECT fid idd, name
    FROM users, 
         friends 
WHERE uid = 33456
    AND fid = id
```

But would give me unnexpected results

Comment: try to use fully qualified names like friends.uid etc.. this will remove the possibility of name clash.

Comment: what do you want to get? the name of friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  id, fid, name
FROM users,friends where users.id=friends.fid
WHERE users.id = 33456
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  id, fid, name
FROM users
INNER JOIN friends ON users.id=friends.fid
WHERE users.id = 33456
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,name from users where id in (select fid from friends where uid=33465)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will return all ID with the name of your friends.

```
SELECT b.fid, c.name
FROM users a INNER JOIN friends b ON a.id = b.uid
     INNER JOIN users c on b.fid = c.id
WHERE a.id = 33456
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.name,u.id 
FROM users u 
WHERE u.id IN 
(
SELECT f.fid 
FROM users u INNER JOIN friends f ON u.id = f.fid 
WHERE f.uid = 33456 
)
```